# tkinter canvas in grid has extra space

Tags: python, canvas, grid, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a canvas inside a frame and I've said the canvas should be 250x250.  But for some reason it is being created bigger, with extra space on the right and bottom.  Here's my code... any ideas?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from player import player0

alpha = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.boardsize = 250
        self.sqsize = self.boardsize//5
        master.title("Canvas with extra space")
        self.initialdraw()
        self.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def initialdraw(self):
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(5,5,5,5))
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

        self.board = Canvas(mainframe, width=self.boardsize, height=self.boardsize,bg='white')
        self.board.grid(row=1,column=0)

        for row in range(5):
            for col in range(5):
                top = row * self.sqsize
                left = col * self.sqsize
                bottom = row * self.sqsize + self.sqsize -2
                right = col * self.sqsize + self.sqsize -2
                rect = self.board.create_rectangle(left,top,right,bottom,outline='gray',fill='')

        self.board.focus_set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    gui = GUI(tk)
    tk.mainloop()
```

The result is this:

[image: canvas with extra space]

I would rather avoid the white gutter on the right and the bottom of the canvas after the smaller squares have been drawn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canvas has a border, controlled by the `borderwidth` attribute. It also has another border controlled by the `highlightthickness` attribute. Set both of those to zero and your canvas should be exactly the size you set it to be.

The `border` attribute is typically used to provide a 3D effect -- a raised border, sunken boarder, or a couple other variations. The `highlightthickness` (and `highlightcolor`) attributes define a solid outline used to denote that the widget has the keyboard focus.

Comment: A very enlightening answer!  Thanks, the board does look much cleaner without the borders, and the geometry actually makes sense.  Seems to me like the Canvas coordinates should not include the border... why in the world would 0,0 be outside the viewable area, in the border?

Comment: @ChrisIrwin: I don't know. I've always found it odd that 0,0 was in the border. It's been that way for a couple decades, and the tk developers rarely make backwards-incompatible changes.

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes:

```
self.boardsize = 249
self.sqsize = 50#self.boardsize//5
```

and

```
top = row * self.sqsize +2
left = col * self.sqsize +2
bottom = row * self.sqsize + self.sqsize
right = col * self.sqsize + self.sqsize
```

It will draw correctly. You can see that the gray border lines are correct on all 4 sides:

[image]

Comment: With this answer I realize that the upper left square is sort of being drawn out of bounds on the top left with my original code.  That's what I didn't understand, and why the gutter existed.  Still not sure why 249 is better than 250 though...

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the canvas isn't the proper size, it just provides a workaround.

Comment: @Bryan: True, I was able to make it work but wasn't sure why. I upvoted your answer because it explains the reason.